# Why does Samsung Galaxy S5 use the values-sw320dp dimens file

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add support for various DPI screens and failing miserably. I have created the following folders:

```
values
values-sw320dp
values-sw480dp
values-sw600dp
values-sw720dp
```

Now, I'd have thought that the Samsung S5 would have picked it's dimens file from the sw720dp folder - given it's resolution is 1080 x 1920

However it appears to be taking it's dimens from sw320dp which results in text that is way too small.

Why does it do this, and can someone provide an authoritative list of sensible values folders to implement.

Comment: `sw` prefix is a `smallest width`. So `sw320dp` is for screens with physical width of 320 dp and more. S5 screen width is 360 dp. So it is correct, that it usus those values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resolution of 1080 x 1920 is not in `dp`, it is in pixels.

Per https://material.io/devices/, the S5 is an xxhdpi device, i.e., 3 pixels per `dp`. This makes the resolution in `dp` **360 x 640dp**, hence why it uses the `values-sw320dp` folder.